# NodeJS MongoDB async call serial is getting disturbed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using foreign key strategy for MongoDB to map sub_id in subscription table...while mapping I have given console log for debugging purpose as I am not getting an appropriate result since 3 days... I want it to iterate for each result cursor generated by first find().

here is NodeJS server API

```
connection((db) => {
    db.collection('gyms').find().toArray(function(err, main_results) {
        if (err) throw err;

        main_results.forEach(main_result => {
            subscriptions = main_result.subscriptions;
            console.log(subscriptions);
            console.log(subscriptions.length);
            if (subscriptions.length == 1) {
                latest_sub = subscriptions[0];
            } else {
                latest_sub = subscriptions[subscriptions.length - 1];
            }
            console.log(latest_sub);
            db.collection('subscriptions')
                .findOne({
                    _id: ObjectId(latest_sub.sub_id)
                }, function(err, sub_results) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(main_result);
                    console.log(latest_sub)
                    console.log(sub_results);
                    main_result.latest_plan = sub_results.name;
                    var date = new Date(latest_sub.date);
                    console.log("kab kiya? " + date);
                    var newDate = new Date(date.setTime(date.getTime() + sub_results.validity * 86400000));
                    console.log("kab khatm hoga?" + newDate);
                    validity = Math.floor((newDate - new Date()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
                    console.log("validity" + validity);
                    console.log("--------------------------------------");
                    if (validity >= 0) {
                        main_result.validity = validity;
                    } else {
                        main_result.validity = -1;
                    }
                });
        });

        function myRes() {
            res.json({
                success: true,
                data: main_results
            })
        }
        setTimeout(myRes, 3000);
    });
});
```

console logged

```
[ { sub_id: '5a4b365f378e1c0b18862582',
    date: 2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z } ]
1
{ sub_id: '5a4b365f378e1c0b18862582',
  date: 2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z }
[ { sub_id: '5a4b3666378e1c0b18862583',
    date: 2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z } ]
1
{ sub_id: '5a4b3666378e1c0b18862583',
  date: 2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z }
[ { sub_id: '5a4b366f378e1c0b18862584',
    date: 2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z } ]
1
{ sub_id: '5a4b366f378e1c0b18862584',
  date: 2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z }
[ { sub_id: '5a4b3666378e1c0b18862583',
    date: 2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z } ]
1
{ sub_id: '5a4b3666378e1c0b18862583',
  date: 2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z }
[ { sub_id: '5a4b366f378e1c0b18862584',
    date: 2017-12-28T18:30:00.000Z } ]
1
{ sub_id: '5a4b366f378e1c0b18862584',
  date: 2017-12-28T18:30:00.000Z }
{ _id: 5a4b368c378e1c0b18862585,
  join_date: '2017/12/20',
  gender: 'Male',
  owner: 'A',
  name: 'A',
  address: '14 shree om darshan, sai nagar',
  state: '—',
  city: 'Nashik',
  pin_code: 422004,
  phone: 9370555444,
  email: 'alpesh.vasani857@gmail.com',
  username: 'A',
  subscriptions:
   [ { sub_id: '5a4b365f378e1c0b18862582',
       date: 2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z } ] }
{ sub_id: '5a4b366f378e1c0b18862584',
  date: 2017-12-28T18:30:00.000Z }
{ _id: 5a4b365f378e1c0b18862582,
  name: 'for A',
  validity: 111,
  price: 111,
  availability: true }
kab kiya? Fri Dec 29 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
kab khatm hoga?Thu Apr 19 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
validity106
--------------------------------------
{ _id: 5a4b3697378e1c0b18862586,
  join_date: '2017/12/20',
  gender: 'Male',
  owner: 'B',
  name: 'B',
  address: '14 shree om darshan, sai nagar',
  state: '—',
  city: 'Nashik',
  pin_code: 422004,
  phone: 9370555444,
  email: 'alpesh.vasani857@gmail.com',
  username: 'B',
  subscriptions:
   [ { sub_id: '5a4b3666378e1c0b18862583',
       date: 2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z } ] }
{ sub_id: '5a4b366f378e1c0b18862584',
  date: 2017-12-28T18:30:00.000Z }
{ _id: 5a4b3666378e1c0b18862583,
  name: 'for B',
  validity: 222,
  price: 222,
  availability: true }
kab kiya? Fri Dec 29 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
kab khatm hoga?Wed Aug 08 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
validity217
--------------------------------------
{ _id: 5a4b36a3378e1c0b18862587,
  join_date: '2017/12/20',
  gender: 'Male',
  owner: 'C',
  name: 'C',
  address: '14 shree om darshan, sai nagar',
  state: '—',
  city: 'Nashik',
  pin_code: 422004,
  phone: 9370555444,
  email: 'alpesh.vasani857@gmail.com',
  username: 'C',
  subscriptions:
   [ { sub_id: '5a4b366f378e1c0b18862584',
       date: 2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z } ] }
{ sub_id: '5a4b366f378e1c0b18862584',
  date: 2017-12-28T18:30:00.000Z }
{ _id: 5a4b366f378e1c0b18862584,
  name: 'for C',
  validity: 333,
  price: 333,
  availability: true }
kab kiya? Fri Dec 29 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
kab khatm hoga?Tue Nov 27 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
validity328
--------------------------------------
{ _id: 5a4b36c8378e1c0b18862588,
  join_date: '2017/12/20',
  gender: 'Male',
  owner: 'C',
  name: 'C',
  address: '14 shree om darshan, sai nagar',
  state: '—',
  city: 'Nashik',
  pin_code: 422004,
  phone: 9370555444,
  email: 'alpesh.vasani857@gmail.com',
  username: 'C',
  subscriptions:
   [ { sub_id: '5a4b3666378e1c0b18862583',
       date: 2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z } ] }
{ sub_id: '5a4b366f378e1c0b18862584',
  date: 2017-12-28T18:30:00.000Z }
{ _id: 5a4b3666378e1c0b18862583,
  name: 'for B',
  validity: 222,
  price: 222,
  availability: true }
kab kiya? Fri Dec 29 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
kab khatm hoga?Wed Aug 08 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
validity217
--------------------------------------
{ _id: 5a4b36dc378e1c0b18862589,
  join_date: '2017/12/29',
  gender: 'Male',
  owner: 'C',
  name: 'C',
  address: '14 shree om darshan, sai nagar',
  state: '—',
  city: 'Nashik',
  pin_code: 422004,
  phone: 9370555444,
  email: 'alpesh.vasani857@gmail.com',
  username: 'C',
  subscriptions:
   [ { sub_id: '5a4b366f378e1c0b18862584',
       date: 2017-12-28T18:30:00.000Z } ] }
{ sub_id: '5a4b366f378e1c0b18862584',
  date: 2017-12-28T18:30:00.000Z }
{ _id: 5a4b366f378e1c0b18862584,
  name: 'for C',
  validity: 333,
  price: 333,
  availability: true }
kab kiya? Fri Dec 29 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
kab khatm hoga?Tue Nov 27 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
validity328
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: Statements within 1st query is normal statement + 2nd query....  AND 2nd query only includes set of normal statements..... and at the end resoponse is generated....BUT  the line by line flow is not followed..it is responding like.....first executes all statments found between 1st and 2nd query and then after that all the statements of 2nd query get executed...i have confirmed about opening and closing of brackets{}()..since i am using promisess still it is not as expected.

Comment: what issue you face ?

Comment: Solved it by using promises resolver, .then, .then hierarchy.